# What would be good Latin names for modern book categories?

Tags: modern-life

There are various ways to order/group books in a library.

- By author, in alphabetical order
- By size
- By category
  etc.

Concerning 3) we might have the following names in Latin. They might be opera...

- linguistica
- historica
- geographica
- religiosa
- philosophica
- medica
- litteraria
  and of course all kinds of conceivable subcategories.

But what about

- *cookbooks*
- *do-it-yourself / handicraft guides*
- *travel guides* (**itinerarium** might be a good candidate, but would e.g. Lonely Planet count as one? According to [this entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D78%3Aentry%3Ditinerarius) it is an account, not an exhaustive guide of useful travel information)
- *belles-lettres*, "a label for literary works that do not fall into the major categories such as fiction, poetry, or drama" (quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belles-lettres)).
- *comic books* (Asterix Gallus et al.) [Edit: I just thought of *delineata*, analogous to the way map publishers like Blaeu would mention the people who drew the map: "X **delineavit**"]

Comment: This is an interesting question! Would it make sense to split it up and ask about each genre separately? That way each one would get proper attention.

Answer (score 6):

Apicius provides us *De re coquinaria*, so a form of that probably works.

Do-It-Yourself guides would fall under the technical genre, which I don't believe the ancients ever fully labeled, but we could perhaps use the Greek *didactica*, from which we get the English "didactic."

Travel guides were already a thing in antiquity. Strabo's was simply called *Geographica*, but a little bit later we do see *itineraria* that could theoretically be used. The latter were more travelogues (M-W def. 1), though.

Belles-lettres isn't really a genre, but a meta-category of different genres.

Comics would be harder to think up, because there was no such ancient analogue. The one thing I can think of is that embroidered images were called *picturae textiles*, so perhaps something with *pict-*. Could be something as simple as *opera picta*, but since it didn't exist back then, who knows what term the Romans would have used?

Answer (score 3):

For handicraft, perhaps [**daedalea** or **daedala**](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=daedalus&filter=CUTF8) would be fun:

> 1. Daedălēus, a, um, adj., Daedalian, relating to Daedalus:
>    (a). Daedălēo Icaro, Hor. Od. 2, 20, 13: "Ope Daedălēa", id. ib. 4, 2, 2.—
>    (b). Daedalĕum iter (i. e. through the labyrinth), Prop. 2, 14, 8 (3, 6, 8 M.).—
> 2. Daedălĭcus, a, um, adj., skilful: manus, Venant. 10, 11, 17.—